# Route API, doesn't work on server but local works well

Tags: laravel, api, server

When I call this API  locally it works fine and return the values.But when i call those APIs after deployment on server, always return Token Key is required.I put the accurate token key from database too.

This is my token function for each user.

```
private function randomDigit($length, $count)
    {
        $codes = [];
        $stringDigits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        while (count($codes) < $count) {
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $randomString = (string)$randomString . substr($stringDigits, rand(0, strlen($stringDigits) - 1), 1);
            }
            if (!in_array($randomString, $codes)) {
                $codes[] = (string)$randomString;
            }
        }

        return $codes;
    }
```

This is how my route looks like.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'token'], function (){

    Route::get('/api/users', 'UserController@apiUsers')->name('api.users');

    Route::get('/api/user/{id}/show', 'UserController@apiUserShow')->name('api.user.show');

    Route::delete('/api/logout', 'UserController@apiLogout')->name('api.logout');

    Route::post('/api/user/{id}/state', 'UserController@apiState')->name('api.state');

    Route::get('/api/user/{id}/getstate', 'UserController@apiGetState')->name('api.getState');

    Route::get('/api/fetch', 'UserController@apiFetch')->name('api.fetch');

    Route::get('/api/init', 'UserController@apiInit')->name('api.init');

    Route::post('/api/user/{id}/present', 'UserController@apiPresent')->name('api.present');

    Route::get('/api/user/{id}/retrieve', 'UserController@apiRetrieve');

    Route::get('/api/user/{id}/getattand', 'UserController@apiGetAttend')->name('api.getAttand');

});
```

Comment: Please try adding the related code and improving the style of your question.

Comment: Try testing your local api again on an incognito browser. Where did you register that route? on `web.php` or `api.php`?

Comment: i registered all of my route in web.php. I test all of my api in postman and the browser too. it's works in local

Comment: @dexterb, The APIs which doesn't need token are working like login API. But others API which need token are not working.

Comment: @dexterb .. here's my route looks like and the function to generate the token key.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually just recreating the already out of the box feature of Laravel.

You should register your API routes on `api.php`. And in your `users` table, make sure you have the `api_token` column there. This column is a 60-characters long random string. When your user registers, you can fill the api_token with `str_random(60)`.
And in your `api.php`, this is how it should look like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('/fetch', 'MyAwesomeController@someFunction');
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request->user();
    });
});

// the above will then create http://example.com/api/fetch route
//  and http://example.com/api/user
```

Then after you made those changes, that's it.

```
// below will return the authenticated user using the api_token`
GET - http://example.com/api/user?api_token=XXXXXXX

GET - http://example.com/api/fetch?api_token=XXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally It's works now. Actually the problem is not about the code error! It is because of nginx configuration. nginx cannot get the get request because of this.
I changed this line of code in nginx configuration into

```
location / {
    try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
}
```

Like this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```